# To ignore Pipe in pipe delimited file

Tags: shell, unix, csv, awk

I am having a file with `|` separated in which I need to search for the char in 3rd column and replace with it with null. I need to replace only the column where character occurs in 3rd field.

file1.txt

```
xx|yy|xx|12
```

output file:

```
xx|yy||12
```

I achieved with this by

```
awk 'BEGIN {FS=OFS="|" } $3 ~ /[[:alnum:]]/ { $3="" }1' file
```

But what I faced is if there is any column having a pipe char that should consider as single column it shouldn't be counted as a field separator.

```
xx|yy|"xyz|xx"|AAA|12...
```

So the output should be like this:

```
xx|yy|"xyz|xx"||12
```

so AAA should replace with null considering as AAA as 4th column.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it belongs on [unix.se].

Comment: @Cole"Cole9"Johnson You are incorrect. Awk programming is perfectly on-topic on Stack Overflow, although it is certainly possible to write off-topic awk questions if one tries hard enough.

Answer (score 4):

With `GNU awk` you would need to use  [**`FPAT`**](http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Splitting-By-Content.html) to describe what a field is instead of using `FS` to describe what the field separator is. For example:

```
$ cat file
xx|yy|AAA|12
xx|"yy|xx"|AAA|12

$ awk '{$3=""}1' OFS='|' FPAT='([^|]+)|("[^"]+")' file
xx|yy||12
xx|"yy|xx"||12
```

However you'd might be better of using a higher level language that has a [CSV parsing](http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) module such as python.

Answer (score 0):

I like @sudo_O's answer, I'm just not sure why it works since `"yy` satisfies the first part of the FPAT RE `[^|]+` so I don't know why gawk wouldn't assume THAT is a field rther than holding off and treating it as part of the larger `"yy|xx"` which matches the second part of the FPAT, `"[^"]+"`.

Anyway, if you don't have gawk, you can always change the "FS" either between fields or inside quoted fields to some other character (e.g. `\t`) before operating on your input just by treating `"` as the FS initially:

```
$ cat file
xx|yy|"xyz|xx"|AAA|12

$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="\""} {for (i=1;i<=NF;i+=2) gsub(/\|/,"\t",$i)}1' file
xx      yy      "xyz|xx"        AAA     12

$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="\""} {for (i=2;i<=NF;i+=2) gsub(/\|/,"\t",$i)}1' file
xx|yy|"xyz      xx"|AAA|12
```